# equals between base and extended class does not work correctly

Tags: java, spring, configuration, java-8, equals

I'm using Java 8 and Spring. Recently I had an weird (for me) issue. Basically, I have two classes:
1. It is a base class:

```
public BaseClass {
    private int variableA;

    public BaseClass() {
        /* this is an empty costructor */ 
    }

    public BaseClass(int a) {
        this.variableA = a;
    }

    /* getter and setter method */

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
       if (this == o) {
            return true;
       }
       if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
           return false;
       }
       BaseClass that = (BaseClass) o;
       /* (HERE) */
       return variableA == that.variableA;
   }
}
```

2. A @Configuration class, which extends the base class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "config")
@RefreshScope //org.springframework.cloud.context.config
public MyClass extends BaseClass {
    private int variableB;

    /* getter and setter method */
}
```

All I want is to check if two classes are equal, taking under consideration only variables in baseClass. Example method

```
public boolean areTheyEqual(BaseClass a, MyClass b) {
    return a.equals(b);
}
```

In the method `areTheyEqual` the classes `a` and `b` are correctly filled. When you look to `BaseClass.equals` to line where `(HERE)` is written: in this point I have some `BaseClass` created from `MyClass`. It is not NullPointer, but `variableA` is equal to 0 (in MyClass it was set to some value). I don't know why!

but

if I change the method `areTheyEqual` to:

```
public boolean areTheyEqual(BaseClass a, MyClass b) {
    return a.equals(new BaseClass(b));
}
```

everything works fine. I'm really curious why is that. Is it some problem that, using `equals` I'm casting @Configuration class MyClass to Object and then to BaseClass?

EDIT 1:
Example:

```
@Component
public class Example {
    private MyClass myClass;
    private BaseClass baseClass;

    @Autowired
    public Example(MyClass myClass) {
        this.myClass = myClass;
        this.baseClass = new BaseClass(myClass);
    }

    @Scheduled
    private void checkMe() {
        if(!areTheyEqual()) {
            /* do something */
        }
    }

    private boolean areTheyEqual() {
        /* baseClass.variableA == 2 AND myClass.variableA == 2 */
        return baseClass.equals(myClass);
    }
}
```

In my question is not important what is `equals` implementation (btw method is generated by Intellij).

My definition of 'works fine' is :
1. When `variableA` in baseClass is the same as `variableA` in myClass then `equals` returns true
2. If not 1. then false

Comment: can you show us the equals code pls

Comment: We can't answer this because there is too much code missing, and we don't know what your definition of "works fine" is.  What do you mean by "in `MyClass` it was set to some value"?  Where was it set, and how?  Your question is totally unclear.

Comment: Show your equals method inside `BaseClass`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: please see now.

Comment: Writing an `equals()` method that works on subclasses is not trivial, and the correct form may change depending on a particular situation.  Sometimes you want the `getClass()` to be equal, sometimes you don't.  http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html is a good resource that discusses the issues, but there are others that I can't find right now.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should stop using the word “class”, when you actually mean “object” or “instance”. Your abuse of the term makes the entire question very hard to read.

Then, you get what you ask for. In your `equals` implementation, there is the statement:

```
if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
    return false;
}
```

which implies that two objects can only be equal, when they are of exactly the same class, so an instance of `MyClass` can’t be equal to a direct instance of `BaseClass` that is not an instance of `MyClass`.

If you want to treat all instances of `BaseClass` and its subclasses equally, regardless of their actual type, you have to change that statement to

```
if (o == null || ! (o instanceof BaseClass)) {
    return false;
}
```

The `instanceof` operator accepts instances of subclasses of the specified type. You don’t need to check the type of `this` then, as it’s implied that `this instanceof BaseClass` is always `true`.

Note that unlike an invocation of `o.getClass()`, `instanceof` also handles `null` correctly, so it is also possible to reduce the statement to

```
if (! (o instanceof BaseClass)) {
    return false;
}
```

But it’s a coding style decision whether to use the simpler form or the explicit `null` test.

By the way, when your intention is that all `BaseClass` instances have the same definition of equality, regardless of their actual (sub)type, you should make the `equals` method `final`, for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

With the little information given, the most probable cause seems to be you redefined the same private variable `variableA` in the subclass, like:

```
public class BaseClass {
    private int variableA;

    public BaseClass (int a) {
        this.variableA = a;
    }
}

public class MyClass extends BaseClass {
    private int variableA;

    public MyClass (int a) {
        this.variableA = a;
    }
}
```

If you do this, the base class' variable will remain 0 in the subclass instance, but you'll still see it having properly set variable called `variableA`, as long as you're looking at the subclass. If you cast it to superclass, the base class' variable will become visible, showing `0`.

Comment: in BaseClass is variableA and in MyClass is variableB. There is no redefinition here.